# What happens if the second reviewer for a conference proceeding keeps missing their deadline?

Tags: journals, peer-review, editors

I have submitted a journal article to a conference proceeding which will be held in June this year. Though I submitted it on time in December and the first reviewer accepted it in the first week itself, still I didn't receive a second reviewer's response. In the online submission system it appears as initial submission status, with the phrase "reviewer missed the deadline" repeated thrice in red color. If I cannot get a second guest editor what will happen to the article? Is it possible to accept an article without a second editor? How long would this usually take?

Comment: Have you asked the conference organizers?

Comment: Seems like that's entirely up to them and it might depend on the first reviewer's input. Someone else might come along here with more info on how these things normally progress, but I'm doubtful anyone will be able to give you a definitive answer besides the actual conference organizers.

Comment: Here is another opinion : ask the conference organisers...

Comment: Really, it seems that you are full of anxiety and so you want encouragement that there is still hope for your article. Sorry, but emotions aside, if you actually want a working solution, then do what the other comments are saying: ask the conference organizers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not your problem but the conference organizer's one. They have to ensure a proper reviewing process.

Usually, they are contacting the reviewer and apply some pressure. It they still get no review, they acquire a third reviewer as replacement (or a program committee member does it by themselfes).